# Problem on CORS configuration with Web Api 2, OWIN and Identity Server

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api2, owin, identityserver3, webapi2

I have a few web applications under the same domain, all using a stand alone Identity Server 3 app for login purposes. Under test environment, every single one of then are under the same domain (http://192.168.100.1, or by dns http://companyServer).

Recently, one application needed to request some data from another app, and I found the following error when debugging on Visual Studio:

Cross-Origin Request Blocked: The Same Origin Policy disallows reading the remote resource at http://companyServer:60000/MyApp/Api/Company/Info?parameter=123. (Reason: CORS header 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' not present).

We have a central library responsible for configuring Web API on our systems, it has the following (among other things):

```
public static IAppBuilder UseCebiUtilWebApi(this IAppBuilder app, CebiWebApiOptions options)
{
    Logger.Debug("Configuring Web API");

    app.UseCors(CorsOptions.AllowAll);

    ...
}
```

On the same method, we also configure Identity Server.

I also checked on my Login Server App, and there is the following code regarding CORS:

```
public class CompanyCorsPolicyService : DefaultCorsPolicyService
{
    public CompanyCorsPolicyService()
    {
        base.AllowAll = true;
    }
}
```

This method is being called on the project's Startup.cs.

As far as I know, every single end of my environmet should be enabling full CORS access, no matter the origin. But the header is still missing.

I've tried quite a few solutions on the internet:

[Using "config.EnableCors" instead of "app.UseCors"](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39398644/5890312)

[Overriding GrantResourceOwnerCredentials,](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24989769/cors-is-not-working-in-web-api-with-owin-authentication)

I have also tried setting up manually some CORS related headers on Web.Config, but I was unable to find the specific question here on SO.

I don't think identity server is related to this problem, but since that is the difference between my evironment and the solutions I've found, I decided to put it in here too.

Any ideas?

Comment: Do you have the OPTIONSVerbHandler configured in IIS. Just run in to something similar myself and it's intercepting all OPTIONS (CORS Pre-Flight) requests.

Comment: @phuzi that was it! I forgot to come back in the day to say it. Do you mind posting and answer so I can mark it as correct?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's possible that the `OPTIONSVerbHandler` could be intercepting all `OPTIONS` (CORS pre-flight) requests.

Try disabling that so that ASP.Net can handle those requests instead.